# TryUpdateModelAsync with modified value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I update my database with model binding like this:

```
var adminUpdate = await _context.Admins.FindAsync(Id);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Password)) {
    if (Password != PasswordCheck) {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "Passwords do not match");
    } else {
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Password + Configuration["SomeLocation:SomeKey"]);
        data = SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(data);
        password = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
    }
} else {
    password = adminUpdate.Password;
}

if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
    return Page();
}

if (await TryUpdateModelAsync(
    adminUpdate,
    "",
    a => a.FirstName,
    a => a.LastName,
    a => a.Email,
    a => a.Password, // must be the value of "password"
    a => a.Status,
    a => a.CompanyId
    ))
{
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Redirect("/admin");
}
```

My problem is, that I need to insert the "password"-variable in the database Password-field instead of the a.Password.

How can I do that?

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks for the answer. The only place I hadn't already tried. Please post your comment as an answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, the call to `TryUpdateModelAsync` ends up setting properties on your `adminUpdate` instance based on values found in `ModelState`. If you want to set another value for `Password`, you can just do so after the call to `TryUpdateModelAsync`, like this:

```
if (await TryUpdateModelAsync(
    adminUpdate,
    "",
    a => a.FirstName,
    a => a.LastName,
    a => a.Email,
    a => a.Status,
    a => a.CompanyId
    ))
{
    adminUpdate.Password = password;
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Redirect("/admin");
}
```

In the example above, I've also removed `a => a.Password` from the `TryUpdateModelAsync` as it is now redundant - whatever value gets set there is overridden in the explicit assignment before the call to `SaveChangesAsync`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to add new line (right above TryUpdateModelAsync )

```
adminUpdate.Password = password;
if (await TryUpdateModelAsync(
    adminUpdate,
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually tried that, but my mistake was that I thought I had to include a => a.Password in the TryUpdateModelAsync for that value to be stored in the database (upgrading from ASP Classic many things is new to me). :)