# .net core MVC TryUpdateModelAsync passed expression of expression node type 'NewArrayInit' is invalid

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

when I use TryUpdateModelAsync method to update Model I give this error, any one have an idea about this

> The passed expression of expression node type 'NewArrayInit' is invalid. Only simple member access expressions for model properties are supported.

Code for this issue is as below.

```
 [HttpPost,ActionName("Edit")]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public async Task<ActionResult> EditLocaton([ModelBinder(typeof(EncryptDataBinder))]int id, IFormCollection formCollection)
 {
 ModelState.Clear();
 LocationModel location = new LocationModel();
 try
 {
 await TryUpdateModelAsync<LocationModel>(location, "", p => new object[] { p.ID, p.Name, p.Code, p.RowVersion });
```

code for the Location Model

```
public class LocationModel : BaseEntity
    { 
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [Display(Name = "Location Name")] 
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string enID { get; set; }
    }
```

Please help for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-7.0#recommended-httppost-edit-code-read-and-update) for `TryUpdateModelAsync`.

```
var studentToUpdate = await _context.Students.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.ID == id);
    if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Student>(
        studentToUpdate,
        "",
        s => s.FirstMidName, s => s.LastName, s => s.EnrollmentDate))
    {
        try
     ...
```

It updates the `studentToUpdate` using data provided in the incoming request.

So I'm afraid you can try `await TryUpdateModelAsync<LocationModel>(location, "", p => p.enID, p => p.Name, p => p.Code);`. In your code snippet, I don't find `RowVersion`  in your `LocationModel`, not sure about it.

Comment: I also found a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53702422) here.